# ZF2 Getting filtered value of other field within a validator

Tags: php, zend-framework2

The situation has come up several times where there is a need to be able to access the filtered value of a different form element from within a validator. For example, we have a phone number validator that needs to know which country to validate the phone number against.

Even if this was going to be set using an option on the validator, the option would still need to be set using the filtered country value from the form.

Does anybody have any experience with working around situations like these?

**edit**

I am aware of the `$context` argument that is passed to the `Callback` validator upon validation, however it only contains the input *as it was submitted* and therefore not filtered and not helpful.

**edit**

I am able to achieve what I am looking for below although I really don't like the implementation and it will not work in many common form scenarios. I am really hoping there is a better way. This example is not based on the country example above but it has the same idea.

```
<?php
class MyValidator extends \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator {
    public $form;

    public function isValid($value) {
        $filtered_values = $this->form->getInputFilter()->getValues();
        var_dump($filtered_values);
    }
}
$validator = new MyValidator();
$factory = new \Zend\Form\Factory();
$form = $factory->createForm([
    'input_filter' => [
        [
            'name' => 'foobar',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => [$validator]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'date',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'DateTimeFormatter',
                    'options' => [
                        'format' => 'Y-m-d g:i:s a'
                    ]
                ],
                ['name' => 'StringToUpper']
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
$validator->form = $form;
$form->setData([
    'foobar' => 'abc123',
    'date' => 'August 3, 2014'
]);
$form->isValid();
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'foobar' => string 'abc123' (length=6)
  'date' => string '2014-08-03 12:00:00 AM' (length=22)
```